# Get active adapter in C#

Tags: c#

I used the following code to get the active network card of the system.
My problem is that the active network card of my system is Wi-Fi, but the system detects Local Area Connection!
While this network card does not exist!

I tried this :

```
var activeAdapter = networks.First(x => x.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback
                                && x.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Tunnel
                                && x.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
                                && x.Name.StartsWith("Ethernet") || x.Name.StartsWith("Wi-Fi") || x.Name.StartsWith("Local") == true );
label2.Text = activeAdapter.Name;
```

Comment: The premise of your question is incorrect: a Windows computer can have more than 1 active network adapter (e.g.: _multi-homing_, VM virtual networks, etc)

Comment: Note that `&&` has higher precedence that `||` so you need parentheses for th eOR conditions

Comment: `x.Name.StartsWith("Ethernet") || x.Name.StartsWith("Wi-Fi") || x.Name.StartsWith("Local") == true` <-- Don't do this, because the human-readable name of network interfaces is localized - so your code won't work on a German or Japanese machine, for example.

Comment: @Dai I have no problem with this because this program is for Iranians and mostly these three channels

Comment: @KlausGütter I will check this but before I added the local section I had no problem and it was picking the correct network card code

Comment: @Dai What is the solution to find the main network in use?

Comment: Redefine your question, as it is based on an incorrect premise. Perhaps you want the adapter matching the default gateway route?

Comment: @AmooReza Again, there's no concept as a "main network". I'm getting the idea that you want to find the adapter used to access the Internet, or at least has a _routable connection_, in which case you need to check which adapter has a valid IPv4 or IPv6 _Default Gateway_ set. That should eliminate irrelevant choices most of the time. Though if the user has a VPN connection set-up, as I imagine most tech-savvy people in Iran are, you'll run into issues - why not just prompt the user to select a connection? (And may I ask what your software _actually does_?)

Comment: @Dai Thank you for the tip!
The part that I have asked the question is used to change the DNS of the system!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

precedence of logical operators

```
      && x.Name.StartsWith("Ethernet") || x.Name.StartsWith("Wi-Fi") || x.Name.StartsWith("Local") == true );
```

shoudl be

```
     && (x.Name.StartsWith("Ethernet") || x.Name.StartsWith("Wi-Fi") || x.Name.StartsWith("Local") == true ));
```

Comment: Protip: enable the "[Wrap binary operators in parentheses for clarity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0047-ide0048)" option under C# Options in VS.

Comment: i used ( ) and fixed problem

Comment: Thanks of @pm100 ( fixed with your answer )